# Option type annotation/hinting for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a more or less standard type annotation or type hinting for option type à la SML, in Python?

So far, I'm writing something like this:

```
def f(a: str) -> str | None:
    …
```

Is this the recommended way to say the result may be of a given type or else `None`? If it is not, then what would be the recommended way?

I had a look at the `typing` module from Python 3.5, and could not find any, unless I overlooked it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting from python3.5 the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#module-typing) module provides the [`Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional) type exactly for this purpose:

```
from typing import Optional

def f(a: str) -> Optional[str]:
    ...
```

Comment: Why not leave a real ellipsis and make it syntactically correct python ;-)